# How to force Newtonsoft Json to serialize all properties? (Strange behavior with "Specified" property)

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Fellow programmers,
I've encountered a strange behavior in Newtonsoft.Json.

When I'm trying to serialize an object looking like this:

```
public class DMSDocWorkflowI
{
    [JsonProperty("DMSDocWorkflowIResult")]
    public bool DMSDocWorkflowIResult { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DMSDocWorkflowIResultSpecified")]
    public bool DMSDocWorkflowIResultSpecified { get; set; }
}
```

Using this simple call with no custom converters / binders / contract resolvers:

```
var testObject = new DMSDocWorkflowI();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

or even with `JToken.FromObject(...)` I always get only one property:

```
{
   "DMSDocWorkflowIResultSpecified": false
}
```

When I attach the trace writer, it catches only this:

```
[0]: "2016-08-30T11:06:27.779 Info Started serializing *****DMSDocWorkflowI. Path ''."
[1]: "2016-08-30T11:06:27.779 Verbose IsSpecified result for property 'DMSDocWorkflowIResult' on *****DMSDocWorkflowI: False. Path ''."
[2]: "2016-08-30T11:06:27.779 Info Finished serializing *****.DMSDocWorkflowI. Path ''."
[3]: "2016-08-30T11:06:27.780 Verbose Serialized JSON: \r\n{\r\n  \"DMSDocWorkflowIResultSpecified\": false\r\n}"
```

So it seems Newtonsoft.Json treats this "Specified" property somewhat magically.
Can I turn this off?
I need both these properties in resulting JSON with exactly these names.

Comment: This is definitely deliberate behaviour - see https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Serialization/ShouldSerializeTests.cs for example - but I don't know how to control it :( I can't find any documentation about this feature, unfortunately.

Comment: Even if you set DMSDocWorkflowIResult as true, it doesn't serialize it. Deserialization gives it as false which is wrong. You should file a defect.

Comment: changing `DMSDocWorkflowIResultSpecified` to `DMSDocWorkflowIResultSpecifie` works as expected. Is it some how related  to property name's length?

Comment: It's mentioned in the [4.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/4.0.1): *New feature - Added XmlSerializer style Specified property support*.  And the `Specified` property behavior for `XmlSerializer` is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx).

Comment: I think that one possible solution is to write your own custom `JsonConverter`. See more about it here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: @feeeper Not much I can do about it with JsonConverter, because `JToken.FromObject(value);` already returns wrong object.
Edit: I could probably use reflection to get all properties of the value if it is an object and serialize them manually one by one but I'd like to avoid that as it will definately degrade performance.

Comment: The issue is not because of the length of the property, it's because of the name: it ends with `specified`. From the docs, it looks like NewtonSoft treats properties which end with that differently. What you can try is changing up either the attribute or the property name and see what the result of that is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior is mentioned, *very* briefly, in the [Json.NET 4.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/4.0.1): *New feature - Added XmlSerializer style Specified property support*.  The `XmlSerializer` functionality is in turn described in [MinOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx):

> [For optional fields] Xsd.exe generates a public field of type `bool` whose name is the element field's name with Specified appended. For example, if the element field's name is startDate, the `bool` field's name becomes startDateSpecified. When serializing an object to XML, the XmlSerializer class checks the value of the `bool` field to determine whether to write the element.

I feel as though this functionality should be documented [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm), but is not.  You might want to [open a documentation issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) with Newtonsoft.

Since you don't want this behavior, if you are using [Json.NET 11.0.1 or later](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1), you can disable it for all classes by instantiating your own [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) and settting [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers.htm):

```
public static class JsonContractResolvers
{
    // Newtonsoft recommends caching and reusing contract resolvers for best performance:
    // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver
    // But be sure not to modify IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers after the contract resolver is first used to generate a contract.

    public static readonly DefaultContractResolver IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembersResolver =
        new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = true };
}
```

Then pass it to `JsonConvert` as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = JsonContractResolvers.IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembersResolver };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObject, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Or to create a `JToken` do:

```
var jToken = JToken.FromObject(testObject, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
```

If you are using an earlier version, you will need to create and cache a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm):

```
public static class JsonContractResolvers
{
    public static readonly DefaultContractResolver IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembersResolver =
        new IgnoreSpecifiedContractResolver();
}

internal class IgnoreSpecifiedContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.GetIsSpecified = null;
        property.SetIsSpecified = null;
        return property;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use he ConractResolver directly:
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = true } };