# .Net Core Enum Values not serializing after getting the response

Tags: c#, .net, enums, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In .Net Web API core solution i have a class(Message) with variables of enum type as mentioned below

```
public enum MessageCode
{
    [EnumMember]
    NULL_PARAMETER,
    BLANK_PARAMETER,
    EMPTY_PARAMETER,
    INVALID_PARAMETER,
    PARAMETER_TRUNCATED,
    QUERY_NOT_FOUND,
    TERM_NOT_FOUND,
    LIST_NOT_FOUND,
    NO_SEARCH_RESULTS,
    NO_UPDATES,
    NO_DICTIONARY,
    NO_PERMISSION,
    LOCKED_PROTOCOL,
    NO_TERMS_IN_LIST,
    DUPLICATE_TERM
}
public enum MessageType
{
    INFO,
    WARNING,
    ERROR,
    FATAL
}
public class Message
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }

    public bool MessageTypeSpecified;

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public MessageCode MessageCode { get; set; }

    public bool MessageCodeSpecified;

    public string MessageParameters;

    public string MessageText;
}
```

While getting the response for the object (Message) using postman the response was as below

```
 "messages": [
    {
        "messageTypeSpecified": false,
        "messageCodeSpecified": false,
        "messageParameters": null,
        "messageText": "0"
    }
]
```

I was not able to get the enum values in response.
so tried the below options

1. Decorate the Class Property - https://exceptionnotfound.net/serializing-enumerations-in-asp-net-web-api/
2. Decorate the Enumeration - https://exceptionnotfound.net/serializing-enumerations-in-asp-net-web-api/
3. Add the Converter Globally - https://exceptionnotfound.net/serializing-enumerations-in-asp-net-web-api/
4. Mentioning enum member ([EnumMember]) in each enum values.

Nothing worked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You accidentally hit a Newtonsoft feature (not very well documented). A longer description can be found in this 
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223335/how-to-force-newtonsoft-json-to-serialize-all-properties-strange-behavior-with?rq=1).

In short: you have a property named `MyPropertyName` and one named `MyPropertyNameSpecified`,i.e `Specified` appended to other property name, the default behaviour for Newtonsoft is to not serialize `MyPropertyName` when `MyPropertyNameSpecified` is `false`.

The solution to your problem would be either to rename some of the properties or use these settings:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = true }
};
```

To edit JSON serializer settings in a .NET Core project supply the options in your `ConfigureServies` method:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = true };
        });
```

Comment: @Emrah where i need to add this code pls help me out

Comment: I extended the answer to clarify where to put the code.

Comment: Am geting build Error CS0117 'DefaultContractResolver' does not contain a definition for 'IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers'

Comment: Then you must have an older version of Newtonsoft.Json, from what i gather the `IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers` was added in `11.0.1`. I would say you have three options. 1, update Newtonsoft.Json. 2. Implement your own ContractResolver. 3, change the names of the properties.