# Using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize object with properties (abc and abcSpecified--set to false) and abc is left out of json string

Tags: json.net, xunit.net

I created a simple XUnit test to show this using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2.

I've tried including Required = Required.Always, no SerializerSettings, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, etc.  If there's a property called XXX that also has a property XXXSpecified (bool) and when XXXSpecified = false, the property XXX will not be in the SerializeObject json string.  If XXXSpecified = true, the property XXX shows up.  I'm going to create a simple solution as well to test version of Newtonsoft.Json up to latest and going down versions to see how long this has been going on.  My end goal is to get XXX to always show up.  I've checked with several others about this, but I'm hoping someone else can shed some light here.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace ABC.UnitTests
{
    public class ABCTests
    {
        #region Tests

        [Fact]
        public void AbcTest()
        {
            var abc = new Abc
            {
                DefClass = new Def
                {
                    Small = 1,
                    SmallSpecified = false,
                    Prop2 = DateTime.Now,
                    Prop2Specified = true,
                    Prop3 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
                }
            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abc, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            });
            Assert.True(json.Contains("\"prop1\":"));
            Assert.True(json.Contains("\"prop1Specified\":"));
            Assert.True(json.Contains("\"prop2\":"));
            Assert.True(json.Contains("\"prop2Specified\":"));
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #region Test Classes

    public class Abc
    {
        public Def DefClass { get; set; }
    }

    public class Def
    {
        [JsonProperty("prop1")]
        public int Small { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("prop1Specified")]
        public bool SmallSpecified { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("prop2")]
        public DateTime Prop2 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("prop2Specified")]
        public bool Prop2Specified { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("prop3")]
        public DateTime Prop3 { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion    
}
```

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Newtonsoft Json to serialize all properties? (Strange behavior with “Specified” property)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39223335/3744182).  Agree?  (Though changing the `Specified` property to `bool?` isn't an option in any of the answers, that's kind of clever.  You could add that as an answer to the older question, if you want.)

Answer (score 1):

I just worked with a colleague, and the answer is the properties XXXSpecified have to be of type bool?. The property XXX will then show up regardless.