# Some fields missing from API response in postman But It is there in result of controller - asp .net core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am working a asp.net core 6.0 project.

when sending an API, The response of API has all fields until controller's last line.
But in postman some Fields are missing

Example :
Here `ticketed` is missing in postman response. But it is in controller.
I attached the images below.

[image: Screen shot in controller]

[image: Postman response]

Note :
I added NewtonsoftJson nuget package
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.1" />`

in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
                options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>())
                    .AddFluentValidation()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Edit:

AirPriceVM.cs

```
public class AirPriceVM
{
    public string TraceId { get; set; }

    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Data
{

    public IEnumerable<AirPricePricingSolutionVm> AirPricingSolution { get; set; }

}

public class AirPricePricingSolutionVm
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AirPricePricingInfoVm> AirPricingInfo { get; set; }


}


public class AirPricePricingInfoVm
{
    public bool Ticketed { get; set; }

    public bool TicketedSpecified { get; set; }
}


// I removed some properties
```

in Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("price")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<AirPriceVM>> AirPrice([FromQuery] string siteCode, [FromQuery] string marketingMedium, [FromBody] GetAirPriceQuery dto)
    {
        dto.SiteCode = siteCode;
        dto.MarketingMedium = marketingMedium;
        var result = await Mediator.Send(dto);

        return Ok(result);   // until this line API response has "ticketed" . but in postman "ticketed" is missing
    }
```

What did I miss here?
Please anyone help me to find the mistake.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the type of `result`,  From the images you provided, I suspect they are not the same type

Comment: @XinranShen Yes the result are same, In debug mode they are ordered in alphabet but in postman they are ordered like model.

Comment: @XinranShen See the filed named `ticketed`. I searched in postman But result is not there.

Comment: the type of `result` is `AirPriceVM`? But i don't find any properties named `SiteCode` and  `MarketingMedium` in your  `AirPriceVM` model, Can you share your `IRequest<>` class?

Comment: `AirPriceVM` is return type. `SiteCode` is used as an input. `SiteCode` is used for Query`GetAirPriceQuery`

Comment: It's because of your `TicketedSpecified` property.  When `TicketedSpecified` is false,  `Ticketed` is not serialized.  If you have property named `xxx` and also a property with the exact name `bool xxxSpecified`, then the bool property will control whether the `xxx` property is serialized.  See [How to force Newtonsoft Json to serialize all properties? (Strange behavior with "Specified" property)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39223335/3744182).  In fact that may be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @dbc could you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819861/system-formatexception-an-error-occurred-while-deserializing-the-xxx-property-o